# Why if else condition is executing both conditions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

the code is executing both statements if i input number greater than or less than 50 but working fine with exact number 50.

when i remove the statement

```
if int(var2)==var1:
    print("equal")
```

then the program is working fine.

***HERE IS THE CODE***

```
var1 = 50
var2 = input("choose a number = ")

if int(var2)>var1:
    print("greater")

if int(var2)==var1:
    print("equal")
else:
    print("lesser")
```

Comment: Did you mean `elif` instead of inner `if`?

Comment: It's quite possible for your input to be both greater than `var1` and not equal to `var1`. It's not possible for it to be equal to 50 *and* either less than or greater than 50.

Comment: which "both" statement do you mean? You have three.

Comment: thanks guys, I replaced the second if with elif and now the program runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is change the second if statement to an elif statement (elif stands for else if). In your code, what is happening is that the first statement is being considered as one if section and the second if - else section is being checked again. So, in a way, there are two if/if - else sections. Hence, the 2 outputs.  By changing the second if to elif, you'll be reducing the two if/if - else sections to just one and there will be only one output. Try this code:

```
var1 = 50
var2 = input("choose a number = ")
if int(var2)>var1:
    print("greater")
elif int(var2)==var1:
    print("equal")
else:
    print("lesser")
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the second `if` to `elif`:

```py
var1 = 50
var2 = input("choose a number = ")

if int(var2)>var1:
    print("greater")

elif int(var2)==var1:
    print("equal")
else:
    print("lesser")
```

Answer (score 3):

When You add an if it checks all of the conditions until you get out of it and continue your code or have an else.
So, it means when it checks the first if it checks the second if to.
So use elif for the second if.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
var1 = 50
var2 = input("choose a number = ")

if int(var2)>var1:
  print("greater")
elif int(var2)==var1:
  print("equal")
else:
  print("lesser")
```

This way you don't have two separate if blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your instruction `print("lesser")` will be executed if int(var2) != var1, so also if int(var2) > var1